# How to add custom label as hyperlink to record page in lwc

Tags: lightning-web-components, hyperlink

I am seeing many examples of adding hyperlink in the data table. But i want to display a hyperlink as a heading. showing the transactionId as hyperlink and when clicked on it, it should take to that transaction record page. Tried using lightning-formatted-url but it asks for exact url to redirect.
Instead of adding the url into the columns like this

```
 const COLUMNS = [
            {label:'Account Name', fieldName: 'Name',
    type: "url",
    typeAttributes: { label: { fieldName: "Id" }, target: "_top" },
    cellAttributes:{ 
        class:{fieldName:'accountColor'},
    }},
```

how can i add it directly ?

Answer (score -1):

You can use the below code on click of link :
`window.open(window.location.origin + "/" + recordId)`